# Motor Voltage known but nothing else

Tags: voltage, current, motor, resistance

I`ve just got a 1.5-9V motor and I know nothing else. I'm using a 9V battery but I want to know how to change the resistance to slow it down but I have no ways of finding the current flowing through the simple circuit. Help please.

Comment: If you're going to do anything with electronics, including driving an electric motor, buy a cheap DMM. You can get them astonishingly cheap on eBay (although sometimes you get what you pay for). Then you can measure voltage, current and resistance. Don't argue. Just do it.

Answer (score 5):

'Rough' is right. You're going to need a multimeter. While you're waiting for that to arrive, here are a few notes.

You're right to think that you can reduce the speed by adding resistance. It's not very efficient because you waste power as heat in the resistor but for a small motor (e.g., as in a toy) it may be adequate.

Standard practice these days is to use pulse-width modulation (PWM) where full voltage is applied to the motor in short pulses and current is off for the remainder of the time. If this is done at a high enough frequency (maybe 100 times / second for your motor) the motor will run smoothly. By varying (modulating) the pulse width between 0% and 100% you can get infinitely variable speed. The efficiency is much better than the resistor as all the power used is going to the motor. (OK, a little heat is lost in the PWM controller.) Again eBay may be your friend here.

Comment: The `LM293D` is an `H-Bridge Driver` commonly used for PWM motor speed control; sparkfun and adafruit etc. have prebuilt modules great for driving hobby motors.